# imacros loop not working

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am implementing java script to retrieve values from a website and it extracts half of the data in java script loop but same parameters extracts complete data from a website.

Here I get the values for type:SPAN but from div I get only title nothing else

```
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:title" + "\n";
```

for

```
 macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:category EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
    macro +="TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:category EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
    macro +="TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:category EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
    macro +="TAG POS=4 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:category EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
    macro +="TAG POS=5 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:category EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
```

its blank in csv .Where is the mistake ? PLease help me out or suggest any other way to implement the same.Thanks in Advance.

Complete code:

```
var macro1;

macro1 =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "VERSION BUILD=8011895" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n"; 

macro1 +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/ " + "\n"; 

var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";

macro +="TAG POS={{n}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:title" + "\n"; 
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:title" + "\n"; 
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:title  EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:category EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro +="TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:category EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro +="TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:category EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro +="TAG POS=4 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:category EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro +="TAG POS=5 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:category EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 

macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=CLASS:tg<SP>ui-h3 EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:name EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:no EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 


macro +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Extract.csv" + "\n"; 

macro +=  "BACK" + "\n"; 


iimPlay(macro1)

for (var n=1;n<10;n++)
{
iimSet("n",n)

iimPlay(macro)

}
```

Comment: without knowing what site you are working on it is hard to solve the issue.

Comment: My advice to you is to install FireBug addon for FireFox and check out the DIV codes you are trying to extract . https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=search

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I finally figured it out.I used to check in the csv sheet and there was a blank in the columns above and assume that it was empty (even if I expand it) but when I clicked on wrap text above I started to see the text .But I still couldn't click on the individual text ,I guess I need to remove blank spaces before and after.Finally the problem is solved .Thanks again for the support.Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the quick response.I finally figured it out.I used to check in the csv sheet and there were blanks in the columns above and assume that it was empty (even if I expand it) but when I clicked on wrap text above I started to see the text .But I still couldn't click on the individual text ,I guess I need to remove blank spaces before and after.Finally the problem is solved .Thanks again for the support.Have a good day.